# Does `recv` work with bytes or octets, or are they one and the same in the context of POSIX documentation?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, porting, c99

Reading the POSIX reference for socket `send` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html I wonder, what exactly do they mean by "byte" - its traditional/historical meaning, its implied/popular meaning, or something else entirely? I am developing a binary TCP/IP-supported network protocol client-server program, and I would like to properly declare my buffer that I use to pass to `recv`, and being able to properly unpack its data.

Yes, I know it's almost hypothetical issue and probably a chance in a million to hit real problems, but better safe than sorry I guess.

So, do the POSIX guys mean octets really, or are they really implying that for platforms where a byte is say, 7 bits, `send` will deal with arrays with granularity of 7*N? Or maybe it will simply transfer all data bit by bit (size granularity `(7 * n_bytes)` bits)? I mean, since it expects a `void *` buffer...

Which declaration for my `recv` buffer would be most stable across architectures and compilers?

I am using GCC with the following flags (C99, POSIX):

```
cc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic -fexec-charset=ISO-8859-1 -DDEBUG -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

Comment: AFAIK POSIX sockets require `CHAR_BITS == 8`

Comment: @K-ballo: I think so too, but even if that's the case, an "octet" doesn't necessarily have to be a `char`.

Comment: @delnan: If `CHAR_BITS == 8` then a `char` has 8 bits, how wouldn't that be an *octet*?

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes, brainfart on my side. I meant to say: A "byte" isn't necessarily a `char`.

Comment: @delnan: A `char` is a *byte* (by its historical meaning), and if `CHAR_BITS == 8` then its also an octet.

Comment: It's `CHAR_BIT`, not `CHAR_BITS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX defines a byte as being the size of an octet, and defines an octet as 8 contiguous bits. This definitions are in chapter 3 of the POSIX standard, the latest POSIX standard (2008) is at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: Thanks! I wonder which version of POSIX do I specify desired compliance to when I define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` in my (source) files?

Comment: @amn: depends on the value. See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe that byte is the `char` type of C, the smallest possible small integer holding a characater, as supported by the system. (perhaps some strange compiler + target system do have non 8 bits `char`).

`octet` means a byte of 8 bits.

If you think in term of TCP/IP, I believe (IIRC) that it defines the various protocols in terms of 8 bit bytes. TCP is made of transmission of multiple of 8 bit bytes.

But in reality, you should not care that much. Perhaps documenting your prococol in terms of bits could help. A lot of things can make your protocol obsolete (just think of IPv6). If you protocol is really valuable and useful, and well documented, someone will make it live and adapt it.

Comment: Some DSPs have 16 or 32-bit chars, but I don't think their toolchains support sockets. OTOH, some of them have technical docs on how to deal with `fread()` and friends.

Comment: Also, RFCs usually define things in terms of _octets_, and never talk about _bytes_.

Comment: The C language standard says that a "byte" is by definition the size of a `char` object, which is `CHAR_BIT` bits.  It requires that `CHAR_BIT >= 8`.  POSIX imposes the further restriction that `CHAR_BIT == 8`.  A system with, say, 16-bit bytes can conform to ISO C, but not to POSIX.

Comment: Well, if I only use POSIX where apparently `sizeof(char) == sizeof(uint8_t) == 1` and is 8 bits, I have no worries. It **would** be nice to relax my code standards compliance. That way someone could port my code to a non-POSIX system easier :) Like I said, with POSIX, I indeed have nothing to worry about.