# What is the byte?

Tags: c, char, language-lawyer, sizeof

C standard uses the word byte in many different places. Mostly it is something very similar to my understanding of this word - 8 bits long chunk of data.

But :

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand

And:

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1

Later:

> When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the
>   total number of bytes in the array.

So if we consider the machine with `char` having more than 8 bits the observable behavior of this program will be differ from the 8bits char machine.

```
char foo[5];

for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(foo) / sizeof(char); index++)
{
    /* some code */
}
```

So maybe the byte meaning is different in the C standard understanding. Could anyone explain: is byte 8 bits or byte is something different

And one extra question.

is `sizeof(char) == sizeof(array[0])`? Considering the byte size differences

Comment: A byte is *never* guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits - it's just the most common architecture

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1, so `sizeof(foo) / sizeof(char)` is `sizeof(foo)`, which is `5 * sizeof(char)`, which is 5 regardless of how many bits a `char` has.

Comment: If the expression `e`  has type `T`, then `sizeof(e)` is equivalent to `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: Yes I know that but forgot about the 3.6 point mentioned in  @StroryTeller answer

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107133/does-recv-work-with-bytes-or-octets-or-are-they-one-and-the-same-in-the-conte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421101/can-the-size-of-the-byte-greater-than-octet-8-bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **3. Terms, definitions, and symbols**
>
> [3.6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.6) **byte**   addressable unit of data storage large enough to
>   hold any member of the basic character set of the execution
>   environment
>
> NOTE 1 It is possible to express the address of each individual byte
>   of an object uniquely.
>
> NOTE 2 A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number
>   of which is implementation- defined. The least significant bit is
>   called the low-order bit; the most significant bit is called the
>   high-order bit.

This is a byte according to the C standard. Its minimum size is just the amount of bits required to hold the basic character set of the execution environment, i.e. a minimum of 8 nowadays IIRC. The exact size of a byte in bits is encoded in the `CHAR_BIT` macro.

Comment: Fortunately C (++) compilers do not have fun having `CHAR_BIT` != 8 ^^

Comment: some uCs have. I started thinking about it when read a post on another forum.